# Rails ActiveRecord update nested attributes in place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes, idioms

In rails, using `update_attributes` on a model will create nested models based on `association_attributes`. Is there an idiomatic way to make it UPDATE the nested models in place?

For example:

Message.rb:

```
attr_accessible :recipient_attributes
has_one :recipient
accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipient
```

Recipient.rb

```
belongs_to :message
# has an name fied
# has an email field
```

recipient

```
r = Recipient.create
r.create_recipient name: "John Smith", email: "john@gmail.com"
r.update_attributes recipient_attributes: {email: "johns_new_address@gmail.com"}
r.recipient.name # nil  <-- this creates a NEW recipient, so the name is nil
r.recipient.email # johns_new_address@gmail.com
```

Instead, I expect `r.recipient` to be the same recipient record but with a new email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an ID of the nested attribute to update. With no ID present, it assumes a new record.

In reality, of course, it would be in a form. For your example, however:

```
john = r.create_recipient name: "John Smith", email: "john@gmail.com"
r.update_attributes recipient_attributes: {id: john.id, email: "johns_new_address@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: Oh that makes a ton of sense -- would have been obvious had I been working with a has_many association. Thanks!

Comment: If I could +100 this, I would. An interesting side corollary is that I was using an API, so this wasn't already in the form. I had to infer it and add it to the parameters if it was present